# event.keyCode == 13 not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a function to send comments on `enter` (and not send on `shift+enter`):

```
$(msg).keypress(function (e) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

It is working on Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? The comment is not sent? Or it is sent even if shift is pressed?

Comment: not sending on firefox

Comment: press enter and nothing happens

Comment: jQuery normalizes keycodes using `event.which` but you would need `e.which`

Comment: The argument you are accepting is `e` but you are accessing `event`.

Comment: Why are you using `event`?

Comment: And of course, in the one case you're checking `shiftKey` and in the other, you aren't.

Comment: thank you friends! I put e instead of event and it works on firefox too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing in Firefox because you've tried to reference the IE-specific global `event` variable (which Chrome also provides, as a bone thrown to IE-specific code), as [sdgluck pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374130/event-keycode-13-not-working-on-firefox/33374245#comment54542603_33374130). Firefox doesn't have that, and so the code throws an error.

Use the argument your handler is passed (`e` in your example), and use `which`, which jQuery will normalize for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way of doing it is to use this:

```
$(msg).keypress(function(e) {

    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(key == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: No, jQuery normalizes `which` for you, no need for `key = e.keyCode || e.which`.